# Repeating array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

In Python I can create a repeating list like this:

```
>>> [1,2,3]*3
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a concise way to do this in Swift?

The best I can do is:

```
  1> var r = [Int]()
r: [Int] = 0 values
  2> for i in 1...3 { 
  3.     r += [1,2,3]
  4. }
  5> print(r)
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create a 2D array and then use `flatMap` to turn it into a 1D array:

```
let array = [[Int]](repeating: [1,2,3], count: 3).flatMap{$0}
```

If you want to have a general way of doing this, here's an extension that adds an init method and a repeating method that takes an array which makes this a bit cleaner:

```
extension Array {
  init(repeating: [Element], count: Int) {
    self.init([[Element]](repeating: repeating, count: count).flatMap{$0})
  }

  func repeated(count: Int) -> [Element] {
    return [Element](repeating: self, count: count)
  }
}

let array = [1,2,3].repeated(count: 3) // => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note that with the new initializer you can get an ambiguous method call if you use it without providing the expected type:

```
let array = Array(repeating: [1,2,3], count: 3) // Error: Ambiguous use of ‛init(repeating:count:)‛
```

Use instead:

```
let array = [Int](repeating: [1,2,3], count: 3) // => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
let array:[Int] = Array(repeating: [1,2,3], count: 3) // => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

This ambiguity can be avoided if you change the method signature to `init(repeatingContentsOf: [Element], count: Int)` or similar.

Comment: You need to change the count parameter type to Int to use it as an index or coerce from Uint to Int `self.init([Array](count: Int(count), repeatedValue: repeatedValues).flatMap{$0})`

Comment: Ahh, yep it turns out that when I was testing it I was using slightly different code than I posted here. I changed it to better match the original `init` method.

Answer (score 6):

With Swift 5, you can create an `Array` extension method in order to repeat the elements of the given array into a new array. The Playground sample code below shows a possible implementation for this method:

```
extension Array {

    func repeated(count: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        assert(count > 0, "count must be greater than 0")

        var result = self
        for _ in 0 ..< count - 1 {
            result += self
        }

        return result
    }

}

let array = [20, 11, 87]
let newArray = array.repeated(count: 3)
print(newArray) // prints: [20, 11, 87, 20, 11, 87, 20, 11, 87]
```

---

If needed, you can also create an infix operator to perform this operation:

```
infix operator **

extension Array {

    func repeated(count: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        assert(count > 0, "count must be greater than 0")

        var result = self
        for _ in 0 ..< count - 1 {
            result += self
        }

        return result
    }

    static func **(lhs: Array<Element>, rhs: Int) -> Array<Element> {
        return lhs.repeated(count: rhs)
    }

}

let array = [20, 11, 87]
let newArray = array ** 3
print(newArray) // prints: [20, 11, 87, 20, 11, 87, 20, 11, 87]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use modulo operations for index calculations of your base collection and functional programming for this:

```
let base = [1, 2, 3]
let n = 3 //number of repetitions
let r = (0..<(n*base.count)).map{base[$0%base.count]}
```

You can create a custom overload for the `*` operator, which accepts an array on the left and an integer on the right side.

```
func * <T>(left: [T], right: Int) -> [T] {
    return (0..<(right*left.count)).map{left[$0%left.count]}
}
```

You can then use your function just like in python:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 3
// will evaluate to [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Very cool! However, I'd like to lean away from implementing Python syntax in Swift. Probably not good for code readability.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
func multiplerArray(array: [Int], time: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result = [Int]()
    for _ in 0..<time {
        result += array
    }
    return result
}
```

Call this

```
print(multiplerArray([1,2,3], time: 3)) // [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
let arrays = Array(count:3, repeatedValue: [1,2,3])
// [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
var result = [Int]()
for array in arrays {
    result += array
}
print(result) //[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```