# How to create an array by multiplying another array in a functional way?

Tags: swift

I'd like to create an array that contains elements from another array multiplied by some Int value.

Example:

the following code

```
let arr = [1,2,3]
let multiplier = 3
print(function(arr, multiplier))
```

should return

> [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

I know how to make it using nested for loops, but I'm looking for some nifty functional way. I was thinking about `map()` function, but it iterates over each element of a given array, which is not my use case I suppose.

Comment: The duplicate question even has the same example (i.e., repeating `[1,2,3]` three times).

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095943/repeating-array-in-swift

Comment: pls check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096237/2713046

Answer (score 1):

Main idea:

1. Create array of arrays,
2. `flatMap` to one-dimensional array.

Example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
let multiplayer = 3
print(Array(repeating: arr, count: multiplayer).flatMap({ $0 }))
```