# How to image setup in hstack under Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, hstack

I followed the @swiftPunk answer it's working fine. But at the last point I stuck on my first image is not showing properly. Please check attached screenshot.

Updated Code:-

```
struct ImageStackRoundUpr: View {
var friendRiders = ["DTR-CentrImg.jpeg", "1frame_0_delay-0.07s", "frame_7_delay-0.07s"]
var nonFriendRiders = ["DTR-CentrImg.jpeg", "1frame_0_delay-0.07s", "frame_7_delay-0.07s"]
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing:-10) {
        Group {
            ZStack {
                Image("DTR-CentrImg.jpeg")
                     .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                ZStack {
                    Image("Crown")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 23, height: 23)
                        .shadow(radius: 1)
                }
                .offset(x: 0, y: -25)
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(12))
            }
            
            ForEach(self.friendRiders.indices, id: \.self) { rider in
                Image(friendRiders[rider])
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    .zIndex(Double(friendRiders.count + nonFriendRiders.count - rider) )
            }
            
            ForEach(self.nonFriendRiders.indices, id: \.self) { rider in
                Image(nonFriendRiders[rider])
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                    .zIndex(Double(nonFriendRiders.count - rider))
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }.padding(.vertical)
    }
 }
```

Output:-

[image: Screen shot]

My Goal:-

[image: Screen shot]

Can someone please explain to me how to show images under in HStack, I've tried to implement by above but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I updated my answer to address the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With zIndex you can do it

---

### [image]

### Version 1.0.0

```
struct ImageStackRoundUpr: View {
    
    var friendImages = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: -10.0) {

            ForEach(friendImages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Image(friendImages[index])
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
                    .zIndex(Double(friendImages.count - index))
            }

            Spacer()

        }
        .background(Color.green)
  
    }
}
```

---

### Version 2.0.0

**ultimately you would looking for this**

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        zIndexHierarchyView()
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct zIndexHierarchyView: View {

    let imageArray: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            
            HStack(spacing: -30.0) {
                
                ForEach(imageArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    
                    Image(imageArray[index])
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().strokeBorder(Color.black, lineWidth: 3))
                        .zIndex(Double(imageArray.count + imageArray.count - index))  // <<: Here!
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                    
                }
                
                ForEach(imageArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    
                    Image(imageArray[index])
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3))
                        .zIndex(Double(imageArray.count - index))                    // <<: Here!
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                    
                }
                
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color.green)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
        }
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        
    }
}
```

---

### Version 2.0.1

About update: this update made just per request of OP for solving new issue!

---

### [image]

```
struct ImageStackRoundUpr: View {
    
    var friendRiders = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    var nonFriendRiders = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: -10) {
            
            Image("1")
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                .zIndex(Double(friendRiders.count + nonFriendRiders.count + 1))
                .overlay(Image("Crown")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 23, height: 23)
                            .shadow(radius: 1)
                            .offset(x: 0, y: -25)
                            .rotationEffect(.degrees(12)))
            
            ForEach(self.friendRiders.indices, id: \.self) { rider in
                
                Image(friendRiders[rider])
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                    .zIndex(Double(friendRiders.count + nonFriendRiders.count - rider))
                
            }
            
            ForEach(self.nonFriendRiders.indices, id: \.self) { rider in
                
                Image(nonFriendRiders[rider])
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                    .zIndex(Double(nonFriendRiders.count - rider))
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .padding(.vertical)

    }
}
```

Comment: ya its working fine but I stuck on my first image can you please check my updated question....

Comment: @ShamDhiman: I think we spoke last time about stop changing question for solving new issue, and making new question instead of it.

Comment: ok sorry for that. can you please help me

Comment: Thank you so much..... for your reply.. now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var friendImages: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing:-6) {
            Group {
                ForEach(friendImages, id: \.self) { imgeName in
                    imgeName
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                        .zIndex(Double(friendImages.count) - Double(friendImages.firstIndex(of: imgeName) ?? 0))
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.vertical)
    }
}
```

So the key here is the `.zIndex(...)` modifier. You can read more about it in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/zindex(_:)

**Edit:**
To answer the updated question: I wouldn't use three different ForEach loops. Instead, I would simply adjust my array:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var friendImages: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue].repeated(count: 3)
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: -6) {
            Group {
                ForEach(friendImages.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    friendImages[i]
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
                        .zIndex(Double(friendImages.count - i))
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.vertical)
    }
}

extension Array {
  init(repeating: [Element], count: Int) {
    self.init([[Element]](repeating: repeating, count: count).flatMap{$0})
  }

  func repeated(count: Int) -> [Element] {
    return [Element](repeating: self, count: count)
  }
}
```

See this question for reference:  [Repeating array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37095943/repeating-array-in-swift)

Comment: ya i checked your solution but same issue occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution (because all of them in one container) is to use `zIndex` to make them drawing in reverse order, like

```
    ForEach(friendImages.indices, id: \.self) { i in
        Image(friendImages[i])
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1))
            .zIndex(Double(friendImages.count - i))
    }
```

Comment: The approach is the same, how to calculate a correct zIndex for each image is on you.